# store image in database

Tags: mysql, image, gwt, gxt

how to store image in database and retrive from database

Comment: Base64 encode the binary, and store in a blob.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: There are lot of howtos on the net. Like http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon the circumstances. IF you are not having a large number of images then store them in you data base and their datatype should be [blob](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Database/JDBC20Intro/exercises/BLOBPut/index.html). But if you are having a large number of images then store them in extra folder and save the path in your database